# list with all dirs + date of file with oldest last modified date

Tags: batch-file

been doing research all day and I probably could have done this manually but I just want to learn how to do it to expand my knowledge

REQUIREMENTS:
I have a folder with 11xxx subfolders, I need to know when the oldest file within each of these subfolders was last modified

so far I tried to use the dir command to get a list of all folders and the last modified date of each of the files within a folder

```
echo Starting...
@echo off
if exist files.txt (del files.txt)
dir /on /s /tw /a-d | find /v "<DIR>          ." | find /v "File(s)" > files.txt
if exist files1.txt (del files1.txt)
For /F "delims=" %%A in (files.txt) Do Echo %%A >> files1.txt
if exist files2.txt (del files2.txt)
For /F "skip=2 delims=*" %%A in (files1.txt) Do Echo %%A >> files2.txt
@echo on
echo Finishing...
del files.txt
del files1.txt
ren files2.txt files.txt
quit
```

ok so the above gave me a txt file in this format

```
 Directory of C:\TEMP  
2013/12/05  05:30 PM            22,528 6N85.mst  
2011/06/21  12:01 PM        14,108,096 CitrixOnlinePluginWeb.exe  
2014/02/19  01:59 PM               448 extract.cmd  
2014/02/19  03:42 PM                 0 files.txt  
2011/08/04  08:41 AM               216 GLF1C8.tmp  
2011/08/04  08:41 AM             2,630 GLF1C9.tmp  
2011/08/04  08:41 AM                54 GLF1CA.tmp  
2011/08/04  08:41 AM                64 GLF1CB.tmp  
2011/07/05  12:29 PM           239,174 ITMURebootMSG.EXE  
2013/11/28  04:20 PM         2,434,048 msxml.msi  
2013/11/28  12:59 PM         2,066,376 msxml4-KB2758694-enu.exe  
2004/04/15  10:10 AM                79 process.bat  
2012/08/02  12:43 AM             4,594 process.log  
2003/11/04  10:17 AM               376 procs.vbs  
2014/02/18  03:32 AM            16,391 WakeUpAgt.LO_  
2014/02/19  12:04 PM             9,247 WakeUpAgt.LOG  
2005/03/09  09:40 AM         4,630,256 WindowsXP-KB895200-x86-ENU.exe  
2005/10/12  02:06 PM         4,934,896 WINDOWSXP-KB902400-X86-ENU.exe  
2006/05/25  12:12 PM         1,307,376 WindowsXP-KB913580-x86-ENU.exe  
     Total Files Listed:  
               0 Dir(s)  81,741,336,576 bytes free
```

I opened the txt file within excel to get the first 10 chars of each line to get the date in col A,

IMO this approach is wrong, maybe I should be doing it in a different way, anyone care to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, thank you @Mark for helping me understand the for loops in dos, I was having trouble with them yesterday and I just couldn't figure out how they worked but now I think I understand!

one of the problems I found with `%%~tx` was that it didn't extract the last modified date, only the last accessed date, maybe I'm wrong but I figured I'd try a different approach anwyay

```
::delete any files called list.txt if they exist
if exist list.txt (del list.txt)

::loop through all directories including sub-directories
for /d /r %%x in (*) do (
    if exist listTemp1.txt (del listTemp1.txt)

    ::loop through each file within directory, show time last written, sort desc
    for /f "delims=" %%y in ('dir "%%x" /tw /o-d') do (
        ::append listTemp1.txt with list of files
        echo %%y >> listTemp1.txt
    )

    if exist listTemp2.txt (del listTemp2.txt)

    ::append listTemp2.txt with lines containing / in the dates
    find "/" listTemp1.txt >> listTemp2.txt

    ::loop through listTemp2.txt to get last line of file, no delims as the first space is after date and we only need date, set var OLDFile with date and current folder
    for /f %%z in (listTemp2.txt) do set OLDFile=%%z %%x

    ::append list.txt with OLDFile
    call echo %%OLDFile%% >> list.txt
)
if exist listTemp1.txt (del listTemp1.txt)
if exist listTemp2.txt (del listTemp2.txt)
```

the above script gave me the exact result I wanted, which was `<date of oldest file within folder> <folder>`

```
2014/02/20 C:\TEMP\folder 1 
2014/02/19 C:\TEMP\folder 2 
2014/02/19 C:\TEMP\folder 1\folder 2
```

I created temporary txt files since I couldn't pipe for loop results (possible?)

anyways, thanks again @Mark, couldn't have figured out how to do this without your help examples and most importantly the break down which helped me understand the code!

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.  The built-in `dir` command, as you found, can do your sorting for you.  If you only care about the date of the oldest file, let it sort by date modified (descending) and get the last entry in the list.  This should do what you're after, I think:

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d') do set OLDESTFILE=%%~fx last modified at %%~tx
echo %OLDESTFILE%
```

Let me break this down.

The switches to the `dir` command will give you a list of files *only* (`/a-d`), in "brief" form (`/b` - just a list of files, not the typical full `dir` output), and will sort that list by date, descending (`/o-d`).

The `for` loop that wraps around that iterates over each of these files and sets an environment variable to the text in the format:

`C:\TEMP\WindowsXP-KB913580-x86-END.exe last modified at 2006/05/25 12:12 PM`

You can read `for /?` for all of the gritty details about the other `~` modifiers you can use.

If you run this with `echo on`, you'll see that it actually sets this environment variable each time through the loop, overwriting it with each subsequent iteration.  That's ok by us, though, since we only really want the last entry anyway.

Now, if you really only want the date and not the time, that's slightly trickier.  You'll need to use a slightly uglier loop like this:

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d') do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ("%%~tx") do (
        set OLDESTFILE=%%~fx last modified on %%a
    )
)
echo %OLDESTFILE%
```

The inner `for` loop here takes the date and time (e.g., `2006/05/24 12:12`) as a list of arguments.  Since `cmd` uses spaces as delimiters by default, this gives you two tokens, `2006/05/24` and `12:12`.  By specifying `tokens=1` you explicitly tell `for` that you only care about the first of those: the date*.

Hope this gets you going on the right track.  Now that you have the tricky part, you can wrap all of this in a loop that gets you the list of directories you care to run this in.

---

`*`Pedantically speaking, you don't actually need the `tokens=1` there, since `%%a` would only refer to the first token anyway, and the time would be in `%%b`, but I thought it would be useful for illustrative purposes.